# Find maximum value in multidimensional array and return parent key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of company1
            [link] => https://companywebsite1.com
            [result] => 29.814814815
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of company2
            [link] => https://companywebsite2.com
            [result] => 143.723259762
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of company3
            [link] => https://companywebsite3.com
            [result] => 212.202797203
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of company4
            [link] => https://companywebsite4.com
            [result] => 127.884615385
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title of company5
            [link] => https://companywebsite5.com
            [result] => 175.911330049
        )

)
```

How can I get the parent key of the company with the highest result value?
For example a function that would return key 2 because the maximum value here is 212.20

I tried this but it only returns me the maxium value not the key. How can i get the parent key of the company with the maximum result value?

```
function maxMarks($array) {
    $max=0;
    foreach ($array as $Rsult) {
        $max=$Rsult['result']>$max  ?$Rsult['result']:$max;
    }
    return $max;
}
echo maxMarks($result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
function maxMarks($array) {
    $max=0;
    $max_key = '';
    foreach ($array as $key=>$Rsult) {
        $max = $Rsult['result'] > $max ? $Rsult['result'] : $max;
        $max_key = $Rsult['result'] > $max ? $key : $max_key;
    }
    return $max_key;
}
echo maxMarks($result);
```

Comment: Thank you Gautam3164, I will accept this as the correct answer :)